# Bootstrap4 is not recognizing I have python >= 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, bootstrap-4

I am tying to install bootstrap 4 using,

```
$pip install django-bootstrap4
```

and I keep getting

```
RuntimeError: Python 3.5 or later is required
```

However when I run $python I get

```
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Am I missing something? Isn't 3.8 greater than 3.5?

EDIT: I was able to install the package after updating to Python 3.8.2.

Comment: Why django bootstrap?

Comment: I'm pretty new to programming and am following along in an into to python book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to python 3.8.2 and package was able to install.